# Tensorlow - please decipher what the tf.where document says

Tags: tensorflow

Please decipher what the [tf.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) documentation says about what it does when both x and y are provided.

I suppose it tries to say it will produce a result by:

1. Broadcast y to the result shape.
2. Broadcast x to the result shape.
3. Update y with x elements where the condition is true.

Is this correct?

> If x and y are provided (both have non-None values):
> tf.where will choose an output shape from the shapes of condition, x, and y that all three shapes are broadcastable to.
>
> **Returns**
> If x and y are provided: A Tensor with the same type as x and y, and shape that is broadcast from condition, x, and y. Otherwise, a Tensor with shape (num_true, dim_size(condition)).

Answer (score 0):

According to latest document on [tf.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where)

> If x and y are provided (both have non-None values):
>
> tf.where will choose an output shape from the shapes of condition, x,
> and y that all three shapes are broadcastable to.
>
> The condition tensor acts as a mask that chooses whether the
> corresponding element / row in the output should be taken from x (if
> the element in condition is True) or y (if it is false).

For Example:

```
tf.where([True, False, False, True], [1,2,3,4], [100,200,300,400])
```

#It is taking true  index values from [1,2,3,4] that is  [1,4] and false index values from [100,200,300,400] that is [200,300]

Output:

> <tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([  1, 200, 300,   4],
> dtype=int32)>

As you can see output tensor shape  as input numpy arrays.